# Comparing nvarchar param to varchar column is throwing off query estimates even after conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

Jumping right in, here is the basic query I am dealing with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fk_PersonID
FROM            PhoneNumbers p
INNER JOIN      PersonPhones pp ON p.pk_PhoneNumberID = pp.fk_PhoneNumberID
WHERE           p.PhoneNumber LIKE '5%'
```

This query returns 20,480 rows and seems to fine. The execution plan shows a clustered index scan on `PhoneNumbers` estimated 24,521 rows and actually returned 24,516.

The problem comes when I try to parameterize '5%' as `nvarchar(25)` I think because `p.PhoneNumber` is `varchar(14)`. I'm using an nvarchar parameter because I am also searching other columns that are nvarchar.

```
DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(25) = '5%'

SELECT DISTINCT fk_PersonID
FROM            PhoneNumbers p
INNER JOIN      PersonPhones pp ON p.pk_PhoneNumberID = pp.fk_PhoneNumberID
WHERE           p.PhoneNumber LIKE @SearchString
```

In this version, the execution plan shows a clustered index scan on `PhoneNumbers` estimated 2,297.29 rows but actually returned 24,516. Then on the Hash Match for the join and distinct Sort, it warns the `operator used tempdb to spill data during execution`.

So I tried converting the phone number to nvarchar for the comparison:

```
...
WHERE           CONVERT(nvarchar(14), p.PhoneNumber) LIKE @SearchString
```

but it still gets the same bad execution plan. I also tried converting my parameter to varchar like this but that doesn't fix it either:

```
DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(25) = '5'
SET @SearchString = @SearchString + N'%'

DECLARE @SearchStringVarChar varchar(25) = convert(varchar(25), @SearchString)

SELECT DISTINCT fk_PersonID
FROM            PhoneNumbers p
INNER JOIN      PersonPhones pp ON p.pk_PhoneNumberID = pp.fk_PhoneNumberID
WHERE           p.PhoneNumber LIKE @SearchStringVarChar
```

Again, this is part of a customer search where someone may type a name, email address or phone number so the string may or may not contain unicode characters. Why don't my conversion attempts make a difference and how can I solve the poor estimation and tempdb spill?

Comment: Make the parameter varchar. Just because someone types in some non ASCII character doesn't mean you have to include it in the search. When the search is against a varchar phone number column. If the character doesn't convert to something in your varchar codepage then it won't match anything in the column either.

Comment: Also this query is going to be highly vulnerable to parameter sniffing anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith Then it wouldn't match the other nvarchar columns that do contain non-ASCII characters, but that aside, even when I change my parameter to `varchar(14)` it still gives the bad estimation plan. Vulnerable to parameter sniffing? What do you mean?

Comment: In the code you have shown you are using variables not parameters. So these will just use guesses on selectivity. Unlike the literal value which can be compiled based on its actual value. But I assume your production code is using parameters. In that case it will be compiled for the first value seen.

Comment: If you add `option (recompile)` to all the queries do you actually see different estimates because of the datatype or was that a red herring?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the distinction. I am currently using variables representing what will be sproc parameters. I was thinking I would need to use `recompile` on the sproc. Unless there's some better way to run a first name, last name, phone number, email search.

Comment: Ah, running the examples with `option (recompile)`, the last one where using a varchar variable estimates correctly. I didn't realize it hung onto those, but that makes more sense.

Comment: And how about `p.PhoneNumber LIKE CAST(@SearchString As varchar(14))` with the RECOMPILE hint?

Comment: Also succeeds. I think that will work. Thanks for your help!